# Editing specific cells in Word document header

Tags: delphi, ms-word, header, cell

I have a Word document and I need to edit specific cells in a header table. I could replace strings, but in this case I need to replace all cell content (and it can vary, so I can not use replacement). I tried this:

```
dm.WordApp.ActiveDocument.Sections.Item(1).Headers.Item(1).Range.Select; //(accsess header)
dm.WordApp.ActiveDocument.Tables.Item(1).Cell(2,3).select;
```

but the second command does not access the `2,3` cell of the header table, but the first table in the document body.

Could someone help with this issue? I'm using Delphi 10.2.

Answer (score 1):

Use:

```
dm.WordApp.ActiveDocument.Sections.Item(1).Headers.Item(1).Range.Tables.Item(1).Cell(2,3).Range
```

Comment: Thank you so much! I just Added to:
dm.WordApp.ActiveDocument.Sections.Item(1).Headers.Item(1).Range.Tables.Item(1).Cell(2,3).Range.Select; and it worked perfectly.
Thank you.